# Как в базе MySQL PHP обновить значение, если оно меньше, чем новое?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть база данных MySQL и мне нужно, чтобы значение в базе обновлялось только в том случае, если оно меньше нового, иначе не обновлять вовсе. За ранее, спасибо.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['save_score'])) 
{ 
if (isset($_POST['score'])) {$score = $_POST['score']; if ($score == '') {unset($score);}} 
if ($_POST['score']!="" ) 
{ 
if (
    $result=mysql_query ("UPDATE users SET score='{$_POST['score']}' WHERE username='{$_POST['user']}'") 
   ) 
{ 
echo "<div style='color:white' >Результаты сохранены!<br></p></div>"; 
} 
else 
{ 
echo "<div style='color:white'>Неудалось обработать базой<div>"; 
$dar=mysql_error(); 
echo $der; 
} 
} 
else 
{ 
echo "<div style='color:white'><p>Незаполнены все поля.</p></div>"; 
} 
} ?>
```

Comment: Меньше нового чего?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['save_score'])) 
{ 
if (isset($_POST['score'])) {$score = $_POST['score']; if ($score == '') {unset($score);}} 
$score = $_POST['score'];
$user = $_POST['user'];
if ($score!="" ) 
{ 
$checkScore = mysql_query ("SELECT score FROM users WHERE username='$user'");
$checkScore = mysql_fetch_assoc($checkScore);
if ($checkScore['score'] < $score) 
{ 
$result=mysql_query ("UPDATE users SET score='$score' WHERE username='$user'");
echo "<div style='color:white' >Результаты сохранены!<br></p></div>"; 
} 
else 
{ 
echo "<div style='color:white'>Неудалось обработать базой<div>"; 
$dar=mysql_error(); 
echo $der; 
} 
} 
else 
{ 
echo "<div style='color:white'><p>Незаполнены все поля.</p></div>"; 
} 
} ?>
```

Comment: `UPDATE users SET score='$score' WHERE username='$user' AND score<'$score'`

Comment: @ArchDemon, ну или так. Я просто на if посмотрел)